# Collection of config in Spring properties file

Tags: spring, spring-el

I have a config file that looks something like this:

```
reports.email.emailSubject.REPORT1=Report1 subject
reports.email.emailToRecipients.REPORT1=recipient1@email.com
reports.email.emailSubject.REPORT2=Report2 subject
reports.email.emailToRecipients.REPORT2=recipient2@email.com
```

I'm using Spring and want to be able to get all emailSubjects in one go and load them into a collection or an array. So I am imagining a bean with a wildcard (i.e *) in a SpEL expression something like this:

```
@Bean(name = "emailSubjects")
public static List<String> getEmailSubjects(@Value("${reports.email.emailSubject.*}") String[] emailSubjects) {
    return new ArrayList(emailSubjects);
}
```

However, SpEL does not support my wildcard idea. It does, however, support 'Collection Selection' and 'Collection Projection' (see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)) but neither of these seem to be quite what I am looking for.

I'd also need to know what the matched property key was - so I am probably looking for something that returns a Map rather than an collection of Strings.

So the question is, how do I do this. Do I need to write a custom property handler of some sorts?

I'm using Spring 3.2.0

Comment: Do you have the possibility to change the properties file?